# When exactly did nudity become uncomfortable?

Tags: cultural-history

In the present society, there's a certain discomfort associated with nudity. And the reason for the discomfort is obviously not just the untimely and unwelcome sexual arousal it might lead to.

If we go back in history long enough, we will reach an era where this was not the case. For example, when clothes weren't even invented, of course nudity was completely normal.

Somewhere in the middle, this transition happened. When exactly did nudity become uncomfortable and why?

My hypothesis:

Clothes were invented for the practical reason of protecting oneself from severe weather. But then people with more resources started wearing more and more sophisticated clothes until it become a means of signalling high status. Thus no clothes started being associated with very low status and hence the discomfort.

Comment: This is more a question of anthropology than history. Prehistoric humans almost certainly wore some kind of clothing; outside tropical climates, clothing is a physical necessity for most of the year.

Comment: The answer to this probably lies in the development of "morality." Also, to imply that this is a universal cultural norm seems narrow. There are groups of people who don't find nudity uncomfortable (e.g.: African tribes with women that don't cover their breasts). Since mores differ between cultures, the level of acceptance of nudity also varies.

Comment: @choster Anthropology can be considered a sub component of history. :–)

Comment: @e1suave Don't tell that to any historians or anthropologists. :-)

Comment: Where I grew up, from September to May and on any rainy day in between.

Comment: I fail to see how this could be considered off-topic…

Comment: Downvote because it is a request to confirm a hypothesis with no research.  This is a discussion question.  I'm skeptical that there can be an objectively correct answer.  There may be a legitimate question in here, but it will have to be stripped of the discussion and some research will need to be added.

Comment: In the book [Plauges and Peoples](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_1_19?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=plagues+and+peoples&sprefix=plagues+and+peoples%2Cstripbooks%2C438&rh=n%3A283155%2Ck%3Aplagues+and+peoples) by McNeil, he says that the rise of communicable venereal diseases like Gonorrhea and Syphilis in the 1400's led to far more increased modesty in clothing in Europe. But this doesn't answer the question for the middle east or other regions.